# Make "historical-unix" history!

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) has over 300 questions about “The history of Unix systems and their main components”. There's also [historical-unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-unix) which has 24 questions but no usage guidance or tag wiki – which is also being used for the same purpose.

I propose that [historical-unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-unix) be a synonym for [history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history). Unfortunately, I don’t have enough reputation in [history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) to propose synonyms for it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[historical-unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-unix) is not a synonym of [history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) at all. It's about Unix as a product, before there were multiple vendors.

Pretty much any question about [historical-unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-unix) would deserve the tag [history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), because it hasn't been a current product for decades. But the converse is not true. [historical-unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-unix) has a distinct meaning and must stay.

Overall the tag has mostly been used with its correct meaning. I have retagged a few questions where it was misused
[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286787/who-or-what-compiled-usr-share-dict-words)
[2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336084/how-should-linux-have-been-designed-if-differently)
[3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372229/how-do-i-convert-a-relative-to-an-absolute-path-portably-and-robustly)
[4](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373459/how-can-one-verify-the-authenticity-of-getty-running-on-linux)
[5](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419307/is-posix-a-subset-of-single-unix-specification)
[6](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442942/where-can-i-get-the-first-edition-of-minix-os)
and I've written a tag wiki.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I wasn't aware of that specific meaning for "historical Unix" so without a tag wiki or usage guidance it seemed like another way of specifying that those questions were about the history of Unix (in general).

Comment: If it's about Bell Labs Unix, should it then be called [tag:bell-labs-unix] or such? "Historical" is rather vague, in that something like early versions of Linux (or BSD, if Linux doesn't count as Unix) could also be called historical by now. Also, looking at the questions with that tag, there are a few that don't seem to be about a particular software or product, but about a particular feature [or bug](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/361170/170373).

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's a proposed synonym now, though still needs some votes:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/history/synonyms
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: Thanks, Ikkachu. I wasn't aware of the second URL. From there, I discovered that https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest lists all the synonym suggestions that I *do* have enough reputation to vote on. It's a pity this feature is not more discoverable (similar to Review Queues).